# Mariadb day light saving time kotlin

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, kotlin, mariadb

I receive dates as a strings for period 30 october to 31 october when daylight saving is happening.

Relevant data:

```
[
  ["2022-10-30T00:00:00+02:00",103.01],
  ["2022-10-30T00:15:00+02:00",103.01],
  ["2022-10-30T00:30:00+02:00",103.01],
  ["2022-10-30T00:45:00+02:00",103.01],
  ["2022-10-30T01:00:00+02:00",100.49],
  ["2022-10-30T01:15:00+02:00",100.49],
  ["2022-10-30T01:30:00+02:00",100.49],
  ["2022-10-30T01:45:00+02:00",100.49],
  ["2022-10-30T02:00:00+02:00",100.2],
  ["2022-10-30T02:15:00+02:00",100.2],
  ["2022-10-30T02:30:00+02:00",100.2],
  ["2022-10-30T02:45:00+02:00",100.2],
  ["2022-10-30T02:00:00+01:00",99.92],
  ["2022-10-30T02:15:00+01:00",99.92],
  ["2022-10-30T02:30:00+01:00",99.92]
]
```

At 2AM they are multiple values but different GMT

I convert the strings to ZoneDateTime with this line:

```
val zonedTimestamp = ZonedDateTime.parse(timestamp)
                                  .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("GMT"))
```

And the values seems to be ok, they are all consecutive, no duplicates for that 1 hour, no GMT added to them

The field `timestamp` on entity is unique and is of type `ZonedDateTime`.
In mariadb the field is declared as `timestamp` (i have used also datetime but is the same problem).

And on saving of the entities i receive the error `Duplicate entry '2022-10-30 03:00:00' for key 'timestamp'`, somehow mariadb is not taking those `ZonedDateTime` as their values.
I saw suggestions to use `timestamp with time zone` but is not such a thing in mariadb.

Comment: Post text rather than images.

Comment: Show entire example input, not fragment.

Comment: I edit the text, but the ideea is that in kotlin i see in debug all ZonedDateTime are consecutive, unique, 15 minutes difference, but when wanted to be saved in mariadb some changes are happening to this data, no ideea what, is not from my side.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: a column of type timezone is stored as epoch seconds but when you read or write to it looks like a datetime in the time zone of your database connection session.  this can be very painful to deal with; it is almost always a better idea to use a datetime type and, on the client side, produce and expect utc